# Saving an item that has been typed at the combobox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a GUI that can add and update by typing the changes in the combobox

Ex.

```
ID(combobox) 1002
Lastname:(textbox) Esteban
Firstname:(textbox) Aldus
```

then if I click save everything that has been typed would be saved in my database.

I'm a newbie in vb.net

here's my code

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    dt.Clear()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblInfo WHERE stud_id='" & cbSI.Text & "'"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)

if dt.rows.count <= 0 Then

    sql = "INSERT INTO tblStud (stud_id, lastname, firstname) VALUES('"& cbSI.Text & "','" & txtLN.Text & "' , '" & txtFN.Text "');"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    dgList.DataSource = dt

    cbSI.Clear()
    txtLN.Clear()
    txtFN.Clear()
    cbSI.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If so please add it. SO is a place for asking help when you are stuck in something.

Comment: okay.. also please add what error you are getting.

Comment: Is there any reason to run the select sql command and then clear the result? dt.rows.count <= 0 will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

You could try change the if statament to

```
    if dt.rows.count >= 0 Then

    sql = "INSERT INTO tblStud (stud_id, lastname, firstname) VALUES('"& cbSI.Text & "','" & txtLN.Text & "' , '" & txtFN.Text "');"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    dgList.DataSource = dt

    cbSI.Clear()
    txtLN.Clear()
    txtFN.Clear()
    cbSI.Focus()
```

Since, you probably will have more than zero rows on dt.